# How can I generate unique itertools chains?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unique, python-itertools

For example, what's the `itertools.chain()` equivalent of:

```
set.union({1,2,3},{3,4,2,5},{1,6,2,7})
```

(obviously that returns a generator, rather than a set)

Comment: Could you provide some inputs and outputs? It's not clear what you're asking from the terminology used.

Comment: I don't thing you can do this with an iterable: there needs to be some way to see if the current element already exists in the output, thus one needs to store the output and append to it along the way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't anything in `itertools` which will do this for you directly.

In order to avoid yielding duplicate items, you'll need to keep track of what you've already yielded, and the obvious way to do so is with a set. Here's a simple wrapper around `itertools.chain()` which does that:

```
from itertools import chain

def uniq_chain(*args, **kwargs):
    seen = set()
    for x in chain(*args, **kwargs):
        if x in seen:
            continue
        seen.add(x)
        yield x
```

... and here it is in action:

```
>>> list(uniq_chain(range(0, 20, 5), range(0, 20, 3), range(0, 20, 2)))
[0, 5, 10, 15, 3, 6, 9, 12, 18, 2, 4, 8, 14, 16]
```

Alternatively, if you prefer to compose a solution from smaller building blocks (which is a more flexible and "itertoolsy" way to do it), you could write a general purpose `uniq()` function and combine it with `chain()`:

```
def uniq(iterable):
    seen = set()
    for x in iterable:
        if x in seen:
            continue
        seen.add(x)
        yield x
```

In action:

```
>>> list(uniq(chain(range(0, 20, 5), range(0, 20, 3), range(0, 20, 2))))
[0, 5, 10, 15, 3, 6, 9, 12, 18, 2, 4, 8, 14, 16]
```

Comment: thanks @Zero, so what do i need to do to also get the instances that were taken out?

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways you can do this:

1. You can use [`unique_everseen`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.unique_everseen) from the `more-itertools` package [here](https://github.com/more-itertools/more-itertools) as recommended in the Python [itertools recipe](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) documentation.
2. Also, if you scroll down the itertools recipe, you'll see Python's recipe for `unique_everseen`:

   ```py
   def unique_everseen(iterable, key=None):
        "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen."
       # unique_everseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D
       # unique_everseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C D
       seen = set()
       seen_add = seen.add
       if key is None:
           for element in filterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
               seen_add(element)
               yield element
       else:
           for element in iterable:
               k = key(element)
               if k not in seen:
                   seen_add(k)
                   yield element
   ```
3. Interestingly, you can also find this function in `importlib_metadata._itertools.unique_everseen`.

   ```py
   >>> from importlib_metadata._itertools import unique_everseen
   >>> list(unique_everseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB'))
   ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
   ```

   However, I don't think it's meant to be used by us (because of the way they hide this function from us like that).

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
def chain_unique(*args):
    seen = set()
    yield from (v for v in chain(*args) if v not in seen and not seen.add(v))
```

Comment: It works, but I think it's not pythonic to pack so much logic into one line of code